# Python 3 : in a text file, get the x occurrences of a string in the y lines where it occurs

Tags: python, string

I have a text (CountOccurrences.txt)

```
Paris Rome
berlin London Berlin
London Rome London
Paris Berlin Berlin
Rome London
Berlin Madrid
Parisian Berliner
```

I want to count the x occurrences of a string in the y lines where it occurs.

Here is my code

```
f = open('CountOccurrences.txt')

word = input("Enter word to be looked for : ")

oc = 0
li = 0

for line in f:

    if word in line:
        li = li + 1

    words = line.split()
    for i in words:
        if(i==word):
            oc = oc + 1

print('Considering that this search is case-sensitive, \
there are', oc, 'occurrence(s) of the word, \
in', li, 'line(s)')

f.close
```

Here are the results for each word, with, as you can see, 2 problems :

```
Berlin       4 oc, 4 li (pb)
berlin       1 oc, 1 li
Berliner     1 oc, 1 li
London       4 oc, 3 li
Madrid       1 oc, 1 li
Paris        2 oc, 3 li (pb)
Parisian     1 oc, 1 li
Rome         3 oc, 3 li
```

I do not understand what goes wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `if word in line:` will return `True` when `word` is "Berlin", and the line includes "... Berliner..." because it exists as a substring of the "[Berlin]er".

Instead, do the check after splitting the line as  follows:

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for i in words:
        if(i==word):
            oc = oc + 1

    if word in words: # modified part
        li = li + 1
```